# Inverse Laplace Transform of s/(s+1)

Tags: laplace-transform

What is the inverse laplace transform of $\frac{s}{s+1}$?

My work was:
$$
X(s)=\frac{s}{s+1}\\
X(s)=s\frac{1}{s+1}\\
x(t)=\frac{d}{dt}e^{-t}=-e^{-t}
$$

My only issue is that when I check my answer with wolfram alpha, it says that the inverse laplace transform of $\frac{s}{s+1}$ is actually $-e^{-t}+\delta(t)$. What is the correct way to find the inverse transform?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HINT: $$\frac s{s+1}=1-\frac1{s+1}$$

We know, $\mathcal{L}(e^{at})=\frac1{s-a}$

and we can [prove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#cite_ref-39) $\mathcal{L}(\delta(t-b))=e^{-bs}$, put $b=0$

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to solve this problem sorry about the formatting

\begin{align} \frac s{s+a}&=\frac{(s+a)-a}{s+a}\\ &=\frac{s+a}{s+a}-\frac a{s+a}\\ &=1-\frac a{s+a}\\ &=\mathcal{L}[δ(t)-ae^{-at}] \end{align}

Comment: Edit this into your answer to fix formatting: `\begin{align}
&=\frac s{s+a}\\
&=\frac{(s+a)-a}{s+a}\\
&=\frac{s+a}{s+a}-\frac a{s+a}\\
&=1-\frac a{s+a}\\
&=1-\mathcal{L}(ae^{-at})
\end{align}` (You can put a line break before each `&` and before the `\end{align`)

Comment: The inverse Laplace transform of $1$ is $\delta(t)$ not $1$.

Comment: Your delta is up one too many lines.