# Inverse Laplace transform of s/(s + 1)

Tags: inverse-laplace

I'm trying to understand what's the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{s}{s+1}$.

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357391/inverse-laplace-transform-of-s-s1) answer, which is quite clear and concludes that it's $δ(t)-e^{-t}$, which sounds right given the reasoning.

But I also found [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6bx3.png) proof, which calculate the inverse of $\frac{1}{s+1}$, then derives it and adds initial condition; with this proof, assuming $a=b=1$, the reverse transform is $1-e^{-t}$.

I'm not quite sure about what's different between these two conclusions, and I can't find anything wrong with any of them, so I was wondering how those solutions fits together, and if there is any error or approssimation in those proofs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with the second ``solution" is the following:

We have that
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{sF(s)-f(0)\}(t) = f'(t)
\end{align}
but
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{sF(s)\}(t) \neq f'(t)+f(0)
\end{align}
since
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{1\}(t)= \delta(t).
\end{align}
This means that
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{sF(s)\}(t) = f'(t)+\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{f(0)\}= f'(t)+f(0)\delta(t).
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Let write
$$
\frac{s}{s+1}=1-\frac{1}{s+1}
$$
The ILT is thus $\delta(t)-e^{-t}$.